# Uninstall WebSphere MFT

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a complex situation. I have MQ and FTE installed in one Windows server. There were few agents defined long back. Now the coordination and command queue managers are removed long back. However the agent services are still there in the Windows server. I am unable to delete the agent now.

The MQ setup in the server is not required any more. My query is if I uninstall MQ, will be uninstall MFT as well and the agent services?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running MFT agent as Windows service. These steps should help you:

1) First run fteModifyAgent to convert the agent (running as Windows service) to standard agent. This will remove the agent from Windows service list.

2) Run fteDeleteAgent to delete the agent configuration. The output of the command provides a list of MQ objects to delete in agent queue manager. Delete those MQ objects.

3) Then uninstall MQ and MFT.

4) Clean the MFT configuration directory on the file system.